# gt table alignment in tufte Rmarkdown

Tags: r, tufte, gt

I am including gt tables in a Rmarkdown Tufte-style HTML. I want to align the gt tables in the center of the main column, rather than in the center of the HTML spanning both the main column and margin.  I have tried using the fig.align knitr option as well as tab.align command. Here is a repo with an rmd that shows the problem: https://github.com/cassidybargell/gt-tufte. [The gt table spans the main column as well as the margin.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYZZn.png)

Example code of a gt table being used in the Tufte-HTML:

```
tibble(subject = "Joe",
       ytreat = "13",
       ycontrol = "9",
       ydiff = "+4") %>%  
  gt()
```

Comment: Make your own css file is one way to fix it. Here are the lines of code:

.gt_table {
  margin-left: 0 !important;
  margin-right: 0 !important;
  width: 55% !important;
} Thank you to Yaodong Yu for the help!!

Answer (score 3):

Make your own css file is one way to fix it. Here are the lines of code:

```
.gt_table {
  margin-left: 0 !important;
  margin-right: 0 !important;
  width: 55% !important;
}
```

Thank you to Yaodong Yu for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to define a hook function:

```
knitr::knit_hooks$set(gtbl = function(before, options){
if (before) {
paste( '<style> .gt_table {width: 100% !important;} </style>',
       '<div class="figure"><p class="caption marginnote shownote">', 
       options$fig.cap, 
       '</p>', 
       sep="")
} else { "</div>" }
})
```

inside a chunk. Then the chunk option gtbl can be used when a gt table is required as for example:

````
```{r gtbl=TRUE, fig.cap="*Table 1* Energy Trends"}
tblTrends()
```
````

where fig.cap supplies the caption right-aligned.

Hook functions are documented in the [rmarkdown cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/chunk-hooks.html)